# Firebase Database data consumption optimization (observing node only partly)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

On my database, I have Post and User Models
User Model has a lot of information, but when I load the posts, I only need 3 out of like 20 parameters.

What I am currently doing is just loading the entire node. This is obviously not really efficient.
My question: Is it more efficient if I observe all 3 values (making 3 connections) individually or just observe the entire node once (making only a single connection).

I don't know exactly what would be more expensive (higher consumption as making 3 connections is probably not better than 1)

Kind regards

Edit

[image]

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of your database structure ?

Comment: Surely, I have added it. Here I need only "name" and "blocked", the rest is in this particular part of the app not of interest

Answer (score 1):

Firebase always loads complete nodes. While it is possible to get a subset of nodes with queries, that doesn't apply here.

So you will either have to load all nodes and do the subselection client-side, or you'll have to create another higher level node that only contains the three properties that you're interested in.

Which one to choose is highly dependent, and (honestly) largely subjective. The main options:

- You can reduce bandwidth a bit by only loading the three properties, but if you store them as a duplicate you'll then end up paying for the storage of duplicate information.
- You can also store the three properties separately, but not duplicate them. But that means that if you need all properties, you'll need to execute two read operations that then add some overhead and complicate code.

Comment: Okay thank you! So if go .child(uid).child(name) I won’t save data as it’s downloading everything anyway?

Comment: That's loading a single property, so that'll work. But to do that for 3 properties, you're making three calls - each with some overhead for the call and the path, which likely more than balances out the savings of downloading less data.

Comment: Okay thank you! One more question: Is there a difference wether I put "true" or "1" if I set a value? Or is the "true" value converted to "1" on the database? Is this a way to reduce data consumption or not? I just have to know if the value exists.